# Does WSO2 need to be installed on client

Tags: php, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm just starting to investigate the implementation of WSO2 ESB. Basically the "WSO2 ESB Server" will be waiting for messages from multiple suppliers/clients. However, does the client need to have WSO2 installed?

For example a third party could be sending messages from a PHP application on a cloud using WSDL to the WSO2 server...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

WSO2ESB is a server, to send requests, you can use any SOAP clients..